# Prove that $(S,\circ)$ is a non-abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S=\mathbb{R}^{*}\times\mathbb{R}$. We define a binary operation $\circ$ on $S$ by 
$$(u,v)\circ(x,y)=(ux,vx+y).$$
Prove that $(S,\circ)$ is a non-abelian group.

Comment: I think you should accept your other questions first. :)

Comment: how we can prove it is not Closure how we can apply Associativity

Comment: sooner or later you're going to need to actually *prove* that an operation and a set on which it is defined constitutes a group. It might as well be sooner rather than later. You just asked about another group, again, showing no effort or work, and had a full answer handed to you. Model the approach, show some work, and if you get stuck, we'll be glad to get you passed being stuck.

Comment: @leenaadam I don't want to sound like a jerk, but you still haven't accepted **all** your other questions.

Comment: but i donot know how to prove Closure this part is difficult since we have pairs also Associativity if i know some idea then i can prove others property so please help me to to these property

Comment: @leenaadam , if you don't pay attention to what Lays tells you then the odds someone will be willing to help you are going to be pretty small...

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u & 0 \\ v & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\ y & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= \dots
$$

Comment: why you use matrix it is pair of number please just prove at lest 2 of property thanks

Comment: @leenaadam, it is a decent hint, believe me. Please do the matrix multiplication, and then look at the first columns of the three matrices.

Comment: yes you are right i get (ux,vx+y) but why you use 0,1 i mean how you make first matrix from pair can you please give me hint about second property thanks